# ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT fails saying constraint doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, upsert

I'm trying to use new Postgresql 9.5 upsert feature. But for some reason my query saying constraint doesn't exist (when it does).

My query is this

```
INSERT INTO journals (ext_ids, title) VALUES ('{"nlmid": "000"}', 'blah')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT idx_nlmid_journal DO NOTHING;
```

where `idx_nlmid_journal` is unique index on jsonb field created like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_nlmid_journal ON public.journals ((ext_ids ->> 'nlmid'::text));
```

I get error

```
ERROR: constraint "idx_nlmid_journal" for table "journals" does not exist
```

what am I missing ?

Comment: I don't think that having a unique _index_ is the same as having a unique _constraint_.

Comment: But unique index is special case of constraint.

Comment: @expert no. A `UNIQUE` constraint in Postgres creates an index - for the easiest enforcement of the constraint. But it doesn't work the other way around, a unique index does not create a constraint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax you use is not valid for a unique index because a unique index does not create a constraint. You need to remove the `ON CONSTRAINT` and use the index expression instead.

This works:

```
INSERT INTO journals (ext_ids, title) 
VALUES ('{"nlmid": "000"}', 'blah')
ON CONFLICT ((ext_ids ->> 'nlmid'::text)) 
DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Well, the syntax _is_ valid, only it has to reference a constraint, not an index.

Comment: @mustaccio yes, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue. Here is my solution:

```
CREATE TABLE messages_tags
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    message_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE messages_tags 
    ADD CONSTRAINT messages_tags_message_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY
    (
        message_id
    ) REFERENCES messages (
        id
    )
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
;

ALTER TABLE messages_tags 
    ADD CONSTRAINT messages_tags_tag_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY
    (
        tag_id
    ) REFERENCES tags (
        id
    )
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_messages_tags ON messages_tags (message_id, tag_id);

ALTER TABLE messages_tags 
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_messages_tags 
UNIQUE
USING INDEX idx_messages_tags;

INSERT INTO messages_tags (message_id, tag_id) VALUES ($1, $2) ON CONFLICT  ON CONSTRAINT unique_messages_tags  DO NOTHING
```

Comment: doesn't work with partial index